# COMMENT FORM Error: Please type your comment text

Tags: comment-form

**Error: Please type your comment text.**

I Created **COMMENT FORM** but Error happened which is above.

I dont know hot to fix this

**Anyone help me please**

Thank you very much!

Function.php

```php
/** コメント一覧表示部分のコード（CHAPTER 19）*/
function my_comment_list( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
  $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
  <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="comment-author clearfix">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, 65 ); ?>
        <p class="comment-author-name"><?php comment_author_link(); ?><span class="says">says:</span></p>
        <p class="comment-meta"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php comment_date(); ?>
          <span><?php comment_time(); ?></span></a><br />
          <?php edit_comment_link( '(編集)' ); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
          <p><em>あなたのコメントは承認待ちです。</em></p>
        <?php endif;
        comment_text(); ?>
        <p class="reply">
          <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
              'reply_text' => '返信',
              'depth' => $depth,
              'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
            ) ) ); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php }


/** コメントフォームをカスタマイズ（CHAPTER 20）*/
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'comment_form_custom_fields' );

/** お名前、メールアドレス、Webサイト部のマークアップ（CHAPTER 20） */
function comment_form_custom_fields( $fields ) {
  $commenter  = wp_get_current_commenter();
  $req    = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
  $aria_req   = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
  /** 名前の項目 */
  $fields['author']   = '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">お名前</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';
  /** メールアドレスの項目 */
  $fields['email']  = '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">メールアドレス</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span> <span class="small">（メールアドレスは公開されません）</span>' : '' ).'<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';
  /**  ウェブサイトの項目 */
  /* $fields['url']   = '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">Webサイト</label><input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>'; */
  $fields['url']    = '';
  return $fields;
}

/** コメントフォームのラベルをカスタマイズ（CHAPTER 20） */
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'comment_form_custom' );

function comment_form_custom( $form ) {
  global $user_identity, $post;
  $req      = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
  $required_text  = '<span class="required">*</span> が付いている項目は、必須項目です！';
  /** コメントフォーム textarea */
  $form['comment_field']      =  '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">コメント</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';
  /** 要ログイン時 */
  $form['must_log_in']      = '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( 'コメントを残すには、<a href="%s">ログイン</a>してください。', wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) ) . '</p>';
  /** ログイン時 */
  $form['logged_in_as']       = '<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a> としてログインしています。<a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">ログアウト</a>しますか？', admin_url( 'profile.php' ), $user_identity, wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ) ) . '</p>';
  /** コメントフォームの前に表示するテキスト */
  $form['comment_notes_before']   = '<p class="comment-notes">' . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) . '</p>';
  /** コメントフォームの後ろに表示するテキスト サンプルでは空文字をいれて非表示に */
  /* $form['comment_notes_after'] = '<p class="form-allowed-tags">' . sprintf( '次の <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> タグと属性を利用できます: %s', ' <code>' . allowed_tags() . '</code>' ) . '</p>'; */
  $form['comment_notes_after']  = '';
  /** form要素の id */
  $form['id_form']        = 'commentform';
  /** submit ボタンの id */
  $form['id_submit']        = 'submit';
  /** コメントフォームの見出しのタイトル */
  $form['title_reply']      = 'Leave a Reply';
  /** 返信コメント時のタイトル */
  $form['title_reply_to']     = 'Leave a Reply to %s';
  /** キャンセルリンクのテキスト */
  $form['cancel_reply_link']    = '(or Cancel)';
  /** 送信ボタンのラベル */
  $form['label_submit']       = 'Post Comment';
  return $form;
}
```

comments.php

```php
<?php
/****************************************

    comments.php

    コメント一覧や、コメントフォームを表示するための
    テンプレートファイルです。

    カスタマイズしたcomments.php のコードに関しては、
    CHAPTER 19,20 で詳しく解説しています。

*****************************************/
?>
<!-- comments.php -->
<div id="comment-area">
    <?php if ( have_comments() ): /** コメントがあったら */ ?>
        <h3 id="comments">Comment</h3>
        <?php /** コメント一覧の表示 CHAPTER 19 */
        $args = array(
            'type'      => 'comment',           /** コメントのタイプを comment のみに指定 */
            'callback'  => 'my_comment_list',   /** my_comment_list()関数は、functions.php に記述 */
        ); ?>
        <ol class="comments-list" id="custom-comments">
            <?php wp_list_comments( $args ); ?>
        </ol>
        <?php /** コメントページャーの表示 */
        if ( $wp_query->max_num_comment_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div class="comment-page-link">
                <?php $args = array(
                    'prev_text' => '&laquo; Prev',
                    'next_text' => 'Next &raquo;',
                );
                paginate_comments_links( $args ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;

        /** ここからピンバックを表示 */
        $str  = '<h3 id="trackbacks">Trackback</h3>';
        $str .= '<ol class="trackback-list" id="custom-trackback">';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
            if ( get_comment_type() != 'comment' ) {
                $str .= '<li class="clearfix" id="comment-' . get_comment_ID() . '">';
                    $str .= '<div class="trackback-author">';
                        $str .= '<p class="comment-author-name">';
                        $comment_author_url = $comment->comment_author_url;
                        $comment_author = $comment->comment_author;
                        if ( $comment_author_url ) {
                            $str .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $comment_author_url ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . esc_attr( $comment_author ) . '">';
                            $str .= esc_html( $comment_author );
                            $str .= '</a>';
                        } else {
                            $str .= esc_html( $comment_author );
                        }
                        $str .= '</p>';
                        $str .= '<p class="comment-meta">' . '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) . '">' . get_comment_date() .'<span>'. get_comment_time() . '</span><a class="edit" href="' . get_edit_comment_link() . '">（編集）</a></span></p>';
                    $str .='</div>';
                    $str .= '<div class="trackback-body">';
                        if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) {
                            $str .= '<p class="attention"><em>あなたのトラックバックは承認待ちです。</em></p>';
                        }
                        $str .= '<p>' . esc_html( get_comment_text() ) . '</p>';
                    $str .= '</div>';
                $str .= '</li>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $str .= '</ol>';
        if ( $i > 0 ) {
            echo $str;
        }   /** ピンバックを表示 ここまで */

    endif; /** if ( have_comments() ): ここまで */
    /** ここからコメントフォーム CHAPTER 20 */
    if (comments_open()):
        comment_form();
    else: ?>
        <p>現在コメントは受け付けておりません。</p>
    <?php endif;
    if ( pings_open() ) : ?>
        <h3 id="trackback-url">Trackback URL</h3>
        <p><input id="trackback_url" readonly="readonly" value=" <?php trackback_url(true); ?>" type="text" onclick = "this.select();" /></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>現在トラックバックは受け付けておりません。</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- /comments.php -->
```

Comment: That's the error you get when you submit an empty comment. Can you check the request you're generating e.g. using your browser debug tools - does it definitely have a value for the comment field?

Comment: Hello thank you for responce i am not sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: no error for browser i checked but wordpress debug has

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'themebs_javascript_enqueue_scripts' not found or invalid function name in /home/www/myweb/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 303

Comment: Unless that’s a function you wrote yourself I’d guess that’s not the problem. Either there’s a bug in your theme or it’s assuming you’ve activated a plugin that supplies functions it relies on. Since there’s no error in your browser console it looks like the missing scripts are not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your responce so i guess leave this for while may be uppdating wordpress may cause something not sure.